# TypeScript compiler thinks a recursive union type with a type index is a string?

Tags: typescript

[Link to TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Model%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%20%7C%20Model%20%7C%20Model%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Ainterface%20ApiResponse%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Model%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aasync%20function%20main()%3A%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20r%20%3D%20await%20api('foos_and_bars')%3B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(r.bars%5B0%5D.baz.name)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%20Problem%0D%0A%20%20console.log(r.foos%5B0%5D.fuzzies%5B1%5D.name)%3B%20%2F%2F%20Implicit%20any%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Amain()%3B%0D%0Aasync%20function%20api(endpoint%3A%20string)%3A%20Promise%3CApiResponse%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Faked%20response%3A%0D%0A%20%20return%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20foos%3A%20%5B%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Foo%201'%2C%20fuzzies%3A%20%5B%7B%20name%3A%20'Fuzzy%201'%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Fuzzy%202'%7D%5D%20%7D%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20bars%3A%20%5B%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Bar%201'%2C%20baz%3A%20%7B%20name%3A%20'Baz%201'%20%7D%20%7D%20%5D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7DR)

```
interface Model {
  [key: string]: string | number | boolean | Model | Model[];
}
interface ApiResponse {
  [key: string]: Model[];
}
async function main(): Promise<void> {
  const r = await api('foos_and_bars');
  console.log(r.bars[0].baz.name); //  Problem
  console.log(r.foos[0].fuzzies[1].name); // Implicit any
}
main();
async function api(endpoint: string): Promise<ApiResponse> {
  // Faked response:
  return {
    foos: [ { name: 'Foo 1', fuzzies: [{ name: 'Fuzzy 1' }, { name: 'Fuzzy 2'}] } ],
    bars: [ { name: 'Bar 1', baz: { name: 'Baz 1' } } ]
  }
}
```

In the TypeScript code above, I've got a `Model` interface that I intend to function like this:

- Any model is an object with any number of properties
- Those properties can be strings, numbers, booleans, another model, or an array of models.

But if I use this interface and try to read some properties on it, I get compiler errors I would not have expected.

For the first console log, I get:

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | Model | Model[]'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

For the second console log (with the `noImplicitAny` flag enabled):

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'string | number | boolean | Model | Model[]' has no index signature.
```

What have I done wrong with my interface here?

Comment: Why didn't you expect that? Not all of the things `r.foos[0].fuzzies` could be have a `name` property, so unless you explicitly narrow that TS won't assume that will be accessible. The compiler goes by *types*, not by *values*. Similarly not all of them have an index signature (`1[0]` and `true[0]` wouldn't work).

Comment: My reasoning: `r` is an `ApiResponse`, so `r.foos` is a `Model[]`. That means `r.foos[0]` is a `Model`, which means it could have a `fuzzies` property that is a `Model[]`, whose members are `Model`s, each of which could have a `name` property which is a `string`.

Comment: **Could have**, but *doesn't necessarily* - `fuzzies` could also be a string, which may have a first member, but that substring wouldn't have a `name` property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is correct.

The first error message for:

```
console.log(r.bars[0].baz.name);
```

Says:

> Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string | number | boolean | Model | Model[]'.
>   Property 'name' does not exist on type 'string'.

Which is exactly the case.  The compiler doesn't know that `r.bars[0].baz` is of type `Model`, it knows that it **can** be of that type, but it can also be a `string` (or a `number`, etc).
Union types only have properties that all of the included types share.
You can inform the compiler that you know what the type is:

```
console.log((r.bars[0].baz as Model).name);
```

The same error is pretty much the same, the type of `r.foos[0].fuzzies` is not known, it can be one of the types in the union, so you need to let the compiler know in the same way:

```
console.log((r.foos[0].fuzzies as Model[])[1].name);
```